# Rails date equality not working in where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

Say I have `ModelA` and `ModelB`. When I save an instance of `ModelA` to the db it also creates/saves an instance of `ModelB`. In the db I end up with UTC for `created_at` that show up exactly the same. eg:

```
puts ModelA.first.created_at  # Wed, 31 Aug 2011 22:49:28 UTC +00:00
puts ModelB.first.created_at  # Wed, 31 Aug 2011 22:49:28 UTC +00:00
```

So I'd expect a query like the following to return matching records (but it doesn't)

```
# model_instance is instance of SomeModel
ModelA.where(created_at:model_b_instance.created_at)  # returns []
```

But something like this, using to_s(:db) does work

```
ModelA.each do |m|
  if m.created_at.to_s(:db) == model_b_instance.created_at.to_s(:db)
    ...  # found matches here
  end
end
```

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong here? I want to be able to write queries like `ModelA.where(created_at: ... )` but I'm currently stuck having to iterate and match against `to_s(:db)`.

Comment: Two things to try: 1) see what the created_at values are in the db -- maybe there's something off like the time zone (maybe rails is inferring a time zone for one but not the other) 2) look in the rails log at the actual sql query that is being generated by your `ModelA.where` invocation -- maybe it's doing some sort of unexpected thing.

Comment: @John your #1 was mostly right. Although `puts ...created_at` shows up as the same thing the actual value in the database is different by what looks like milliseconds. If you want to post your comment as an answer I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: Not getting:  ModelA.where(created_at:model_b_instance.created_at)  # returns []   is that ModelA.created_at == ModelB.created_at maybe with :joins too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things to try:

1. see what the created_at values are in the db -- maybe there's something off like the time zone (maybe rails is inferring a time zone for one but not the other)
2. look in the rails log at the actual sql query that is being generated by your ModelA.where invocation -- maybe it's doing some sort of unexpected thing.